# SlickGrid - applying getItemMetadata making the row to loose its id

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have the following problem:

[***>>>>>>> Link to a JsFiddle demonstration >>>>>>***](http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/Tvpf5/)

I have used the [collapse example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html), and added getItemMetadata method.

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function (row) {
        var thtId = data[row].id;
        if (data[thtId + 1] && data[thtId + 1].indent > data[thtId].indent) {
            return { 'cssClasses': 'parentClassName' }
        }
    };
```

This works fine until I try to collapse and expanding my rows. Than I get the following error (only on expanding):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

From my experience, this error accrue when the dataView looses the children's properties. 
I investigated more and saw that the code fall in the *appendRowHtml* function (slick.grid.js#1217).

Does anyone has expirience with collapsing feature & getItemMetadata?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution been held by @Tin, creator of SlickGrid

> The exception is occurring in "var thtId = data[row].id", where "row"
>   is out of bounds.  You should check if "data[row]" exists before
>   accessing the "id" property.  The grid asks for a metadata for a
>   non-existent row, which could be interpreted as a bug, but it is still
>   useful to be able to customize the empty last row (the one used for
>   adding new entries), so it kinda makes sense.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/65vPmzXsLMQ